# Closure of the intersection of an open halfspace with a convex set

Tags: general-topology, geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $H$ be an open halfspace and $C$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose that $H\cap C\neq \varnothing$.

Is it true that the closure of the intersection of $H$ with $C$ is equal to the intersection of the closure of $H$ with the closure of $C$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C\cap H \subset \overline{C} \cap \overline{H}$ it follows that
$\overline{C\cap H} \subset \overline{C} \cap \overline{H}$ for
**any** sets $C,H$.

We are given that $C \cap H$ is non empty and since $H$ is open, it
follows that there is a point $x \in H \cap \operatorname{ri} C $.

For any convex set $K$, if $x \in \operatorname{ri} K$ and
$y \in \overline{K}$, then $t y + (1-t) x \in \operatorname{ri} K$
for all $t \in [0,1)$. (To some degree, this is the essence of
the almost 'topological' nature of convexity.)

Suppose $y \in \overline{C} \cap \overline{H}$, then we have
$t y + (1-t) x \in C$ and $t y + (1-t) x \in H$ for all
$t \in [0,1)$. Letting $ t \to 1$ shows that
$y \in \overline{C\cap H}$.

Comment: what do you mean by "ri"?

Comment: @AreaMan: The relative interior. It is the interior relative to the affine hull of the set. For example,  in the plane, the relative interior of the line segment $[(0,0), (1,0)]$ is the  line segment $((0,0), (1,0))$ (that is, it is missing the two end points). It is independent of the 'ambient' space as such, whereas the usual interior is not. For example, the interior of the segment is empty.